# Image link spans over full width

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

Look at this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
img{
    height: 800px;
    display: block;
    margin:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="..."><img src="img.jpg" alt /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

I want only the image to be linked to another page. But this code produces a link for the full width of the browser window. How can I get rid of the linked area next to the image?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with your output

Comment: @Insula What do you mean with output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 'display:block' takes up the whole width.

I think you can use 'text-align' instead of 'display:block' and 'margin:auto'.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        .sample {
            text-align: center;
        }
        img {
            height: 800px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sample">
        <a href="..."><img src="img.jpg" alt /></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```